# How to handle inserts and deletions in the same transaction in Postgres and H2 without unique index violation?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a spring boot project with a postgreSQL database in production and an h2 database for testing. I am updating a nested object via `JpaRepository::save`. The object holds a list of its components who each have their own id and a value under a unique constraint, defined in the SQL schema. Below is a condensed version:

```
@Entity
class Class {
  @Id
  int id

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "class", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  List<Pupil> pupils;
}

@Entity
class Pupil {
  @Id
  int id

  int bookId;
}
```

It can happen that I update an existing `Class 4567` where the unique values have changed, e.g. `pupil 1` is removed and a new `pupil 21` is added with `book 8486` which was previously held by `pupil 1`. As the unique constraint is still valid I expect jpa to execute the update without issues as the "after state" is valid.
However, this is not the case, instead I get

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUPIL_UNIQUE_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.PUPIL(CLASS_ID, BOOK_ID) VALUES (4567, 8486)"; SQL statement:
insert into PUPIL (PUPIL_ID, BOOK_ID) values (?, ?) [23505-191]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUPIL_UNIQUE_INDEX_4 ON PUBLIC.PUPIL(CLASS_ID, BOOK_ID) VALUES (4567, 8486)"; SQL statement:
insert into PUPIL (PUPIL_ID, BOOK_ID) values (?, ?) [23505-191]];
...
```

According to this post: https://mossgreen.github.io/JPA-parent-children-updating-violates-constraint/ JPA does not in fact realize that the after state will be valid but inserts first and then already complains. The post reccomends adding `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to the unique constraint, however that doesn't work on h2 despite my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

I do not want to lose the unique constraint on `bookId` and I cannot just drop h2 as a test database. How can I still make inserts and deletions in one `JpaRepository::save` work?

Comment: How are you indicating the object is to be removed?  you just need a handle on the EntityManager context to call flush on it afterward, which will force the delete statement immediately with any other changes in the context, before you then save/persist the new one.

Comment: I'm indicating that an object is to be removed by removing it from the list of the owner object. In my class pupil example, I save `class 4567` after deleting `pupil 1` from the list, i.e. `class4567.getPupils().remove(pupil1); class4567.getPupils().add(pupil21); classRepository.save(class4567)`

Comment: use saveAndFlush on class4567 then between the remove and the next add.

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: @Chris never mind the code in my previous comment, I guess I simplified too much there. My code does not actually manipulate the list. Instead I get a transport object (with matching id) that is mapped to an object `target_class 4567` of the @Entity classes listed above in the question. I suppose I could then load an entity object from the repository and manipulate it until it matches the target object I received, but ideally I would just pass the target object into the save method and have jpa do the work for me.